# How to proof the existence of the inverse in symmetric group $ S_{n} $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have to proof the existence of the inverse. I think it is $f^{-1}$ for every $f$. 
I have no problem to verify that $f^{-1} \circ f = id$ :

$(f^{-1} \circ f)(x)=f^{-1}(f(x))=f^{-1}(y)=x=id(x)$

But when I have to proof $ f  \circ f^{-1}=id$ (commutativity of the inverse) I get stuck because:

$(f \circ f^{-1})(x)=f(f^{-1}(x))=?$ How should  I continue?

Comment: "I think it is $f^{-1}$" How is your $f^{-1}$ defined? Normally it is *defined* as the unique function such that $f^{-1}\circ f$ and $f\circ f^{-1}$ are both identities. It exists if and only if $f$ is bijective.

Comment: For example if $f(1)=2$ then $f^{-1}(2)=1$ But then if they are functions in $S_{n}$ Does it mean that $f(2)=1$ and $f^{-1}(1)=2$?

Comment: Do you know that every permutation can be expressed as a product of transpositions (i.e. $2$-cycles)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all note that functions in $S_n$ are called permutations and by definition are bijections (i.e. one-to-one and onto). So $f^{-1} (x)$ adopts a unique value, say $y$. Equivalently, $f(y) = x$. Now you may write $$ fof^{-1} (x) = f(f^{-1}(x))=f(y) = x,$$ which implies that $fof^{-1} = id$.